# how to install Stratos 1.5.2

Tags: wso2, openstack, wso2-stratos

this dated install guide, http://wso2.org/project/stratos/1.0.0/WSO2StratosInstallationGuide.html, assumes UEC, but UEC is depreciated (https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/uec.html).

1. Where is the most recent install manule for Stratos?
2. Does Stratos need Eucalyptus or does it support OpenStack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Stratos 1.6.0 is now available for download at http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos

This is a pre-configured local setup. You should be able to install it in your local machine without any trouble.

If you using a mac osx please follow [this article](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-build-apache-stratos-from-source.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install this on ubuntu. I have it installed on CentOS 6.0. The trick is to make sure you have the dependencies installed, which was tricky on centos.

Comment: I dont have a problem with Debain derivatives, Im just not after a single server deployment.